# How to update tableView after alertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have a tableView, that I fill with Realm in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
var data = RealmModel.shared.getSections()
RealmModel.shared.fillTableview(company: "Airbus", plane: "A350", status: false)
RealmModel.shared.fillTableview(company: "Airbus", plane: "A380", status: false)
RealmModel.shared.fillTableview(company: "Boeing", plane: "Boeing 737", status: false)
data = RealmModel.shared.getSections()
statisticsTableView.reloadData()
```

I want to add elements into `tableView` with `alertController`.

```
@IBAction func addPlane(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "На каком самолёте вы летали?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textfield) in }
    let alertCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Отменить", style: .destructive) { (alert) in }
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Добавить", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
    let newItem = alertController.textFields?.first?.text
    RealmModel.shared.fillTableview(company: "Другие", plane: newItem ?? "", status: true)
    }

    alertController.addAction(alertAction)
    alertController.addAction(alertCancel)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    statisticsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

What should I do to tableView updates right after `alertController` is closed because now it only updates after I close the app and then reopen it.

Comment: add `data = RealmModel.shared.getSections()` and `statisticsTableView.reloadData()` as the last statement in your `alertAction` 
`let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Добавить", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
    let newItem = alertController.textFields?.first?.text
    RealmModel.shared.fillTableview(company: "Другие", plane: newItem ?? "", status: true)
    data = RealmModel.shared.getSections()
    statisticsTableView.reloadData()}` that should do the job

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is pretty vague and there are a LOT of things that could be causing the issue. For example, we don't know what the tableView dataSource is. An array? How is it populated? There's nothing in the code that adds anything to that dataSource, therefore the tableView would not have any fresh data. Can you clarify the question by adding more relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I had to reload tableView inside of AlertAction, not after

```
@IBAction func addPlane(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "На каком самолёте вы летали?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textfield) in
    }
    let alertCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Отменить", style: .destructive) { (alert) in }
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Добавить", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
        let newItem = alertController.textFields?.first?.text
        RealmModel.shared.fillTableview(company: "Другие", plane: newItem ?? "", status: true)
        self.data = RealmModel.shared.getSections()
        self.statisticsTableView.reloadData()
     }
    alertController.addAction(alertAction)
    alertController.addAction(alertCancel)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```